# being+ past participle

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

I was listing to an audio file, and the author provided information about the word "ostensible" as :

> Declared as true without being demonstrated or proved, ...

I am confused about the structure of the highlighted.

I think it is abridged version of:

> something which is declared as true without being demonstrated or proved.

The obscure part of this expression, for me, is "without being demonstrated or proved"

I know Being+PP is used for passive progression.  It seems "being demonstrated"
to be a Noun. !Is it a noun clause ? e.g., "where you live"

Comment: The ing-form after a preposition, here "without", is a gerund, not a participle.

Comment: *being* is a Gerund-Participle form of verb. And *without* is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

"Being" is a gerund here, which is used wherever you could use a noun, so yes, it's a noun phrase.  You can replace "being demonstrated or proved" with "demonstration or proof" without significant shift in the meaning, IMHO.

Comment: So why the author did not say without demonstration rather "being demonstrated". Is there any differences ?

Comment: Not in my mind.  As to why, you ought to ask the author that.  I'll refrain from speculation.

Comment: I think it's most like that they chose to use the past participles to match the one at the beginning of the phrase, "declared".

Comment: "being demonstrated" is slightly more precise, as befits a definition, because it implicitly has the same subject as the main clause. "Without demonstration" would say that no demonstration took place, but is not specific about just what is or isn't demonstrated.